# Send a value from a table with post method

Tags: php, html-table, http-post

I have a table like this:

| id  |  title | --
  1      title1     send button
  2      title2     send button

when I click on "send button" it must send that row ID to another page with a form. But the problem is whenever I click on each "send button" it just send first row id! What is wrong with my code and why this happens?

this my code:

```
<table>
   <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>id</td>
           <td>title</td>
           <td>action</td>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php foreach($res as $row){ ?>
   <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <label for="prepay<?php echo $id; ?>">Pay</label>
            <form method="POST" action="payment.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="prepay" id="prepay<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display: none;" />
            </form>
        </td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In your code there is just one ID and one submit button.

Comment: Is this part of a loop? There only is one `echo $row['id']`

Comment: sorry. I edited the code.

Comment: @MSHDeveloper: When each row has own form with submit button, this submit button send just this form, not other forms in website.

Comment: do you mean my code is correct?

Comment: @MSHDeveloper: it seems to be. Submit button can send just the form where is this submit button located. Look into source code (generated html), if you see in each row single FORM, you should see correct ID in hidden input and submit, it should work.

Comment: @MSHDeveloper You may validate the values of the input tags manually with the browsers debugger. Also try to `var_dump($res)` to check the values.

Comment: thank you for your helpful comment. I fix it just with a bit of code. I edited my code its now works. By adding id to label and input ids, forms and their inputs will be separated and there is no interference.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="POST" action="payment.php" id='frm.'{$row["id"]}.''>
  <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" <?php name='{$row["id"]}' value='{$row["id"]}' echo $id; ?>" />
</form>

//this is my code working fine. Change to your mode

 echo "
  <form class='adminForm' id='frm.'{$row["id"]}.''  action='sample1.php' method='POST' target='_blank'>
  <tr class='mt-2 align-center' id='showd'>

    <button type='submit' name='{$row["id"]}' value='{$row["id"]}'>
    <i class='far fa-print text-primary' ></i></button></td>
  </tr>
";

echo'
  <div class="col" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_name" id="c_name" value="'.$row['c_name'].'" />
  </div>
</form>';
```